# Using the word "infrastructure"

Tags: word-usage

Can we classify "dams" and "pipelines" into one word? I'm doing my summary of a passage. Is *infrastructure* suitable?

Comment: You can use "infrastructure," but no one will know that the infrastructure is comprised of dams and pipelines unless you explicitly explain that beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Both dams and pipelines are examples of infrastructure, so in short, you can use it as an umbrella term in this way.  That said, as J.R. says in a comment infrastructure is a very general term that can include a great many things more than just dams and pipelines.  If you provide more context about the passage we might be able to come up with a more specific word.